# Kicad 7 - Resize a board

Tags: pcb-design, kicad, board, edge

I created a board in Kicad, but doing more work on it, I managed to shrink its size.

[image]

All this is unused space.
Is there a way to shrink the board. It is easy to move the edge cuts, but the unused copper still remains.

I searched a lot but I couldn't find an answer to this.

EDIT: This is what happens when I move around the edge cuts and press B to redraw the copper zone
[image]

Comment: You also need to resize the copper pour area

Comment: @Linkyyy And how do I do that?

Comment: You should be able to select it in the corners and resize it if you select the right layer

Comment: Or just press B to refill zones. KiCad doesn't fill zones outside of the board.

Comment: @Hearth I did just what you said and I am getting closer but not completely there. I updated the question with a picture.

Comment: Actually I did it. I just had to move the copper zones as well.

Comment: You don't need to resize the copper pore; it stops at the board perimeter and this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You have two basic options:

1. If your board outline is a rectangle, just select it and drag the corner to the new position
2. If not, I would just delete the existing outline and draw a new rectangle to the proper size.

Don't worry about the copper zones.  They will only fill to the edge of the board.

Quick tip to select the existing outline lines:  Choose the "Highlight mode" to focus on a specific layer

[image: highlight mode button]
[image: Layer selector]

Then choose the Edge.Cuts layer.  Now, you will only select items on that layer

Comment: Thanks! I did the (1) but you can see the results in my edited question. They are not was I was expecting. As for (2), even if I did that, the copper would still remain. I can press `B` to redraw the copper, but I think I will have the same result.

Comment: Actually I did it. I just had to move the copper zones as well.

Answer (score 2):

> *It is easy to move the edge cuts, but the unused copper still remains.*

You don't need to resize the copper pore; the "flood" stops at the board perimeter and this is what you want. It won't affect the design or Gerber files or bare circuit board. If you want to resize it then that's no problem but, it won't make any difference to the finished board at all.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.